# Angular ChartJs colors option not working

Tags: html, angularjs, canvas, colors, chart.js

I am trying to change some colors on my bar chart in AngularJS. The problem is that it seems like it is not taking my settings into consideration and it only displays some default colors, not the ones I set.

This is the code for my chart:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="datta"
    chart-options="diagOptions" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true" chart-colors="colors" chart-series="series"> 
    </canvas>
</div>
```

and here is the array of colors.

```
$scope.colors = ['#ff6384'];
```

It does not take this array into account, that is what its happening. Anyone having any ideas why ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You should put the array as a string value for the attribute.
This is working for me:

```
chart-colors="['#FDB45C']"
```